# HTML5 video slow to start playing on android phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

i am making a phonegap app which shows videos via an html5 video player. The video play fast and fine on ios, but it takes time to start playing on android. it loads some part of the video or maybe the whle video and then plays it. i have given the preload="none" attribute. how do i make the video play instantly?

Answer (score 0):

Android will not preload the video on mobile web implementations. Also, even after the video has been preloaded (the first few bytes), the decoding takes some time on weak devices.

For this reason, your best bet IMHO would be:

- Enable the autoplay without user gesture on the web view that contains your phonegap app

  WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

Then:

- In JS, mute and hide the video, and star to play it
- When the user performs the action that triggers the play, set the video's location to 0, reveal and umute it:

  document.getElementById('myVideo').currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById('myVideo').muted = false;